# Update-notifier package doesn't notify on Kubuntu

Tags: updates, kubuntu, kde, notification, update-notifier

Last week I installed Kubuntu and didn't like to update my packages through plasma-discover.
I've really liked Ubuntu's update-notifier package, which also exists on Lubuntu (update-notifier-qt) and tried to install it on Kubuntu which worked just fine. However no matter what I've tried it won't actually notify me about out-of-date packages unless I manually open it.

Do you know what I could be doing wrong? Or is it just that KDE/Kubuntu is incompatible with it?
When I run systemd-analyze blame, I can see the following services start on each boot:

1. fwupd.service
2. packagekit.service
3. update-notifier-download.service
4. apt-daily.service

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: One week might not have any changes to be notified about. Unattended Upgrades will silently install security upgrades *without* notification or user interaction, so what's left are the rarer non-security bugfixes.

Comment: I have it set to daily though. On Ubuntu, when you run apt update and a package update is available, you immediately get the popup. Also, if I have available updates and click "remind me later" it never does, when on Ubuntu it does so at least on every session. And I've tested with non-security updates (e.g oibaf's mesa ppa, Rob Savoury's vlc3, etc...)